# Восседающая или восседающего?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Гигантская статуя Будды, восседающего на вершине холма в молитвенной позе, хорошо видна из любой точки деревни.

Answer (score 1):

Восседающий Будда - это известно. А вот что такое восседающая статуя - не совсем понятно. Поэтому "восседающего".

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, "восседающая статуя" странно звучит, Морковкин прав. Как может неживая статуя восседать, то есть фактически участвовать в активном действии?!

А статуя Будды, восседающего где-то, аналогична фотографии человека, что-то делающего. Это совершенно естественно.

Comment: Будды, что-то делающего?

Comment: А что такого?***